# opencl clCreateImage clCreateImage2D

Tags: c++, image, opencl

I am new with OpenCl with C++ and I'm trying to create a cl_mem of an image but I don't get to make it work:

First I used clCreateImage2D like this:

```
Mat image=imread("pic.jpg",CV_32FC1);
int width = image.rows;
int height = image.cols;

char *buffer = reinterpret_cast<char *>(image.data);

cl_image_format clImageFormat;
    clImageFormat.image_channel_order = CL_INTENSITY ;
    clImageFormat.image_channel_data_type = CL_FLOAT;
cl_mem Image2DBuffer =clCreateImage2D(context,CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, &clImageFormat, width,height,0,buffer,&error);
```

but it didn't compile and Visual Studio 2012 gave me this error: "error C4996: 'clCreateImage2D': was declared deprecated".

I looked for a solution and I found out that OpenCL 1.2 has replaced clCreateImage2D and clCreateImage3D for clCreateImage (or at least that's what I understood), so I changed the code for which follows:

```
cl_image_desc image_desc;
    image_desc.image_type = CL_MEM_OBJECT_IMAGE2D;
    image_desc.image_width = width;
    image_desc.image_height = height;
    image_desc.image_array_size = 1;
    image_desc.image_row_pitch = 0;
    image_desc.image_slice_pitch = 0;
    image_desc.num_mip_levels = 0;
    image_desc.num_samples = 0;
    image_desc.buffer = NULL;

cl_mem ImageBuffer=clCreateImage(context,CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, &clImageFormat, &image_desc, buffer,&error);
```

but the program crashes at the last line (Unhandled exception at 0x0000000000000000) and I have no Idea why.

I'd appreciate if anyone can help. I guess I wrote everything that you might need to understand the issue, but in case something is missing just let me know and I'll provide extra info.

Comment: Did you declare and allocate error?  Is the image being opened properly?  Is the context being initialized properly?

Comment: Also, your data is char* but the clImageFormat is set to CL_FLOAT

Comment: Two questions that might help: (1) The way `image_desc` is configured, it looks like you are passing a `image2d_array_t` of length 1 into the kernel. Is this what you are intending to do? I.e. does your kernel signature contain an `image2d_array_t` param? If it is just an image2d_t (what I expect based on your inital code), image_array_size should be set to 0 in the image_desc. In some cases transferring 1 image2d_t type may even be faster than an image2d_array_t of size 1. (2) Are you running on Nvidia hardware but using headers from AMD/Intel - which support OpenCL1.2, while Nvidia doesn't?

Comment: If the device you are using is OpenCL 1.1 then using clCreateImage will crash. You have to check if the device is 1.2 before using 1.2 APIs. It is safer, if you are using mixed devices, to use the 1.1 APIs. There is a #define you can set before #including cl.h that will enabled the 1.1 APIs (I'm surprised they are already marked as deprecated for you).

Answer (score 0):

Code below works on VS12, AMD APP SDK v2. Play with first allocation flag, my GPU uses shared memory, so I pick CL_MEM_ALLOC_HOST_PTR.

```
//Let image constructor select row pitch
std::size_t row_pitch = 0, rows = 768, cols = 1024;

Mat image(rows, cols, CV_32F, cv::Scalar(0.0f));
try{
    cl::Image2D img(context, CL_MEM_ALLOC_HOST_PTR | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, cl::ImageFormat(CL_LUMINANCE, CL_FLOAT), image.cols, image.rows, row_pitch, (void*)image.data);
}catch(cl::Error &e){
    cerr <<e.what()<<endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

clCreateImage is 1.2 function.

If your device only supports opencl 1.1, you should use clCreateImage2D or clCreateImage3D and include the 1.1 CL folder.

If you use clCreateImage function in the device not surpport 1.2, the applicatoin will crash when running.

And if you use clCreateImage2D or clCreateImage3D without include the 1.1 CL folder will compile error.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should set

```
image_desc.image_row_pitch = width *channel;
image_desc.image_slice_pitch =  width *channel*height;
```